# Creating a Go slice without make

Tags: arrays, go, slice

```
nums := []int{2, 3, 4}
```

What does this do in go? Am I creating an array or a slice?

From this: https://gobyexample.com/range, it says slice. But I think it is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In go, *array* types include their *length*.  Since you omitted the length it is a *slice*:

```
array := [3]int{1, 2, 3} // Array since it includes length (3).
slice := array[:] // Slice since there is no length specified.

fmt.Printf("%#v - %T\n", slice, slice) // %T means "type".
fmt.Printf("%#v - %T\n", array, array)
// [3]int{1, 2, 3} - [3]int
// []int{1, 2, 3} - []int
```

In the example above, we made a slice without invoking "make" by setting it to the full range of of `array`.  If you were to edit either `array` or `slice` then both will change, since "slice" is essentially a view into the storage that is "array".

```
slice[0] = 456 // And array[0] == 456
array[0] = 789 // And slice[0] == 789
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't specify the length, it is a slice.

An array type definition specifies a length and an element type: see "[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)"

[image: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals_slice-array.png]

> A slice literal is declared just like an array literal, except you leave out the element count.

While a slice can be created with the built-in function called make, you used the literal form to create a slice.

The internal of the created slice differs from an array:

```
make([]byte, 5)
```

[image: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals_slice-1.png]

Answer (score 4):

Actually by doing this:

```
nums := []int{2, 3, 4}
```

You are creating *both*: an array *and* a slice. But since it is a [slice literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), the result will be of slice type, so the type of `nums` is `[]int` which you can verify with this code:

```
fmt.Printf("%T", nums) // Output: []int
```

What happens is that an array will be created/allocated automatically in the background with a length of 3 initialized with the listed elements, and a slice will be created referring to the array, and this slice will be the result of the expression.

Quoting from the [Go Language Specification: Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> A slice literal describes the entire underlying array literal. Thus, the length and capacity of a slice literal are the maximum element index plus one. A slice literal has the form
>
> ```
> []T{x1, x2, … xn}
> ```
>
> and is shorthand for a slice operation applied to an array:
>
> ```
> tmp := [n]T{x1, x2, … xn}
> tmp[0 : n]
> ```

An Array literal also includes the length, for example:

```
arr := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
arr2 := [...]int{1, 2, 3} // Length will be computed by the compiler
fmt.Printf("%T", arr)  // Output: [3]int
fmt.Printf("%T", arr2) // Output: [3]int
```